# How to resolve Google adsense account deactivation because of inactivity for more than 5months but admob activity is tied to same adsense

Tags: admob

For atleast four years now, I closed/shutdown the website I used to run approved Adsense account. One year after I decided to shut down the website, I decided to go into app development program, so I created admob with thesame email I used for Adsense and both of them linked. Since after creating admob I have been earning something with admob apps till date.
But today I got an email from Adsense that my Adsense account hasn't received any ad activity or earnings for more than 5 months. The letter said that I may have previously used this account to set up ads on my site, monetize on YouTube or apply for the YouTube Partner Program. They’re letting me know that in 30 days, my AdSense account will be deactivated.

Please what should I do? I have many apps running admob activity with thesame account tied to Adsense.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob, which is part of adsense but treated separately does not look for websites, but adsense does.

In your case you first had a website and now only use Admob. That's how Adsense sees it.
You should aply for Admob, Here is the link: https://admob.google.com/home/

As far as Adsense is concernd, you are running websites first, and Admob besides that. You probably need a diffrent emailadres (gmail) to aply again. This way it's admob first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
If I create blog site now and add adsense code to it are they going to wave the deactivation?

Comment: If that website is aproved and in good status, then yes, your account would not close.

Comment: Is this activity really needed? How can we get message "AdSense account hasn’t received any ad activity or earnings in the last 6 months" when the app is generating earnings on daily basis and this information is reflected in the AdSense reports??

Comment: Only retards are working at google, seriously, they can't stop doing all kind of stupid nonsense

Answer (score 0):

If AdSense has been deactivated for Youtube but you are still using AdSense for Admob, please review the following Google Support thread for details:

https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/187272261?hl=en